# How to use split() with Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I have a script that opens a text file, reads the lines in a list and then splits the lines using `.split()`.

I want to use the same functionality in Streamlit but `split` throws an exception:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Here is a minimal example as mentioned in the comments:

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

# TIlte of the App
st.title(
"MWE")

#Side bar
st.sidebar.subheader("File Upload")

semi_colon = -5
entry_id = -4

#File upload
uploaded_log = st.sidebar.file_uploader(label="Upload your Log File",type='txt')

if uploaded_log is not None:
    print(uploaded_log)
    try:
    print("Open And readlines")
    eeprom = uploaded_log.readlines()

    print("create lists from the logfiles")
    ##create lists from the logfiles 
    sip_list = [x for x in eeprom if (x[entry_id] == ord('1') and x[semi_colon] == ord(';'))]
    slope_list = [x for x in eeprom if (x[entry_id] == ord('2') and x[semi_colon] == ord(';'))]
    cal1_list = [x for x in eeprom if (x[entry_id] == ord('3') and x[semi_colon] == ord(';'))]
    
    group_of_lists = [sip_list,slope_list,cal1_list]
    group_new = [[l.split(";") for l in group] for group in group_of_lists]

    except:
    print("Error occured")

else:
st.write('Please upload a file to the app')
```

Comment: Can you add a MWE *with streamlit* which isn't working?  BTW you can write your 'list of lists' a lot more cleanly, but let's see how you want to do it in the end first.

Comment: Incidentally I presume your `{first...sixth}_list` are your `sip(etc)_list`

Comment: `the app throws an exception` is the most important thing you should provide us.

Comment: @2e0byo yes they are, I've just changed it in the question

Comment: Thanks!  Note that that's not a full MWE.  You need at least `import streamlit` at the beginning, and an `Except`

Comment: In fact, I don't see how your streamlit code uses streamlit at all!  Could you add a minimal app around it (which fails)?  And we *do* need the exception message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example might help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for every comment, I think I've found out the answer.
Instead of:

```
 group_new = [[l.split(";") for l in group] for group in group_of_lists]
```

It should be:

```
group_new = [[str(l).split(";") for l in group] for group in group_of_lists]
```

The reason for this that the lines are still bytes-like objects, and first they need to be converted to string to use string functions on them. I've found a community post about it as well:
https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/upload-text-file-which-needs-to-be-read-line-by-line/7714/2

Comment: Thank you for adding an answer to clear it up